# Flutter: Native view inside a flutter view embedded in a native app

Tags: ios, flutter

It's a bit of a specific scenario, and I seem to be missing a single detail I just can't get right.
Here's the deal:
I have an iOS app to which I've added a flutter module. All works well, integration's fine. Great.
I now have a specific need to embed a native view inside the flutter view. So, logically, I follow this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views?tab=ios-platform-views-swift-tab .

I got everything, the `UIKitView` on the dart side, the factory and the platform view on the native side.

The only thing left is to actually register the factory and all should be well.

This is where I get stuck, I can't get the registrar because it requires a plugin name!
Docs say:

```
self.registrar(forPlugin: "<plugin-name>")!.register(
            factory,
            withId: "<platform-view-type>")
```

But, `<plugin-name>` is not defined anywhere. Tried the module's name, tried the main class in it, tried `Flutter`, tried `App`, tried `FlutterPluginRegistrant`, tried `AppFramework`... all desperate attempts, but I'm out of ideas.

Any help / hint would be greatly appreciated.